# Preventing CSRF in Angular 2 / ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, csrf-protection

I am working on a sample SPA using ASP.NET MVC for back end and Angular 2 for front end.

I followed below steps to prevent cross site request forgery attacks in my application

1. Since ASP.NET MVC sends a cookie with name "__RequestVerificationToken",  and expects a header with name  "__RequestVerificationToken" in the HTTP request to prevent CSRF , I have added below code in my angular module

   ```
   {provide: XSRFStrategy, useFactory: xsrfFactory}
   ```

where   xsrfFactory is below function

```
export function xsrfFactory() {
    return new CookieXSRFStrategy('__RequestVerificationToken', '__RequestVerificationToken');
}
```

2. And below is the controller action code with "[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]" attribute , to which an AJAX call will be made using Http service of Angular 2.

   ```
   [CustomAuth]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult GetAuthors()
   {            

       List<BookStoreAdmin.ViewModels.Author> authors = BookStoreAdmin.BAL.Author.GetAuthors();

       BookStoreAdmin.ViewModels.Response<List<BookStoreAdmin.ViewModels.Author>> response = new Response<List<ViewModels.Author>>();

       response.success = true;
       response.errorMessage = null;
       response.data = authors;            

       return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   ```
3. Below is the code which makes the AJAX call .

   ```
    loadAuthors(): Observable<AuthorModel[]> {      

        return this.http.get('http://localhost:57599/author/GetAuthors')
       .map((data) => data.json()); 

    }
   ```

   When my application makes an AJAX call using Http angular service , I was expecting it to have request header with name "__RequestVerificationToken" , but this
   header is missing   , any idea what could be the reason ?

Please let me know if more information needs to be provided ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see if you are passing a header in angular2 http call.

You can use [RequestOptions](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptions-class.html) API which allows you to add **`header`**. After adding header when you make request, `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` should be able to receive sent header.

Read more of **`RequestOptions`** here : 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptions-class.html

Comment: As per this [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html) , it should be added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but might be useful for someone.

I think the header is not set because this is a GET request. Though this is Angular 2, the angular 4 [security docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection) might be relevant here as they state that

> By default, an interceptor sends this cookie on all mutating requests (POST, etc.) to relative URLs but not on GET/HEAD requests or on requests with an absolute URL.

In order to explicitly include this header as [@micronyks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3751711/micronyks) states in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42711994/2102114) you can use the [RequestOptions](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptions-class.html) API. Here's a code sample

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('__RequestVerificationToken', <token>);
return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers});
```